# Dynamic PHP / mysql dropdown menu issue

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I can't seem to get this to work. Part of a `$_POST`.

```
<?
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE TID = '".$_SESSION['UID']."'") as $row) 

{
echo '<option value=\" '.$row['UID'].' \">'.$row['FNAME'].' '.$row['LNAME'].'</option>';
}?>
</select>
```

The `_POST`'ed value for `['UID']` keeps coming up as    \"

Tearing my hair out on this one, can't see what must be a very simple error. 
FNAME and LNAME appearing ok, echoing `[UID]` on this page shows the right value so it is something here that is wrong.

Comment: Its because you escape the value, while you don't need to escape it.

echo '<option value="' . $row["UID"] . '" would do just fine

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to slash double quotes here, as you're declaring strings in single quotes.

i.e., try:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['UID'].'">'.$row['FNAME'].' '.$row['LNAME'].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is going to return a result set, not an array. You have to get the result set, THEN extract the data

```
$vals = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE TID = '".$_SESSION['UID']."'");
while( $row = $vals->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['UID'] . '">' . $row['FNAME'] . ' ' . $row['LNAME'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: You're making assumptions about what database driver he's using.  It's entirely possible to have a custom db wrapper that returns an iterable result set when you run `query()`